# Find Thevenin equivalent for a circuit with a current source with both parallel and series resistors

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, thevenin

I'm not quite sure if the Thevenin equivalent I found for the circuit is correct:

[image: Problem Circuit]

To find \$V_{Th}\$, I analyzed the open circuit: as the current between ***A*** and ***B*** is provided by the current source regardless of \$R_{TA}\$ and \$R_{TB}\$, then:

\$V_{Th}=I_A*R_{AB}\$

And to find the resistance from the pov of \$V_{Th}\$ (which should be  \$R_{Th}\$), I turned off the current source and ignored \$R_{TA}\$ and \$R_{TB}\$ which gave that:

\$R_{Th}=R_{AB}\$

I would like to know if there's any error in my solution and if so, how to properly analyze it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is too boring to be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solution is good and have no Error But remember about Dependent Current source You can't turn off that . You can just turn off Independent sources in circuit.